# How to activate the developer mode in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

I've installed Odoo version 10 module but I didn't see the activate developer mode under About section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developer mode has moved from the user screen to `Settings` in Odoo 10+ version.

Click on link "Active the developer mode" or "Active the developer mode (with assets)"

Here is reference for Odoo 10 and will be same for Odoo 11 and 12.

[image: Active Developer mode]

In Odoo 13:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Other way to activate developer mode, when you write into the url.
Example:

```
Original:
http://odoo:8069/web
Debug:
http://odoo:8069/web?debug
Debug with assets:
http://odoo:8069/web?debug=assets
```

This way is better to me, because I shouldn't to switch Dashboard not like your solution.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. But when we update directly via URL, we should put more focus what we have write. To avoid End User complexity, it's better to use menu.

Comment: It is true, but in my opinion this is comfortable to some of developer. Thats why I wrote it to here.